# open existing sqlite3 database under QT

Tags: linux, qt, sqlite

I am very new to QT and SQLite DBMS. I am trying to open an existing database created using "sqlite3" command-line program under ubuntu Linux. The same database I am trying to access under QT using the following code :

```
void MainWindow::func()
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    accounts_db = new QSqlDatabase();
    *accounts_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    perror("? ");
accounts_db->setDatabaseName("/home/user/xyz.db");
QSqlError *a = new QSqlError();
*a = accounts_db->lastError();
perror(a->text().toLatin1());
if (!accounts_db->open()) {
    perror("database open error :");
}
if ( !accounts_db->isOpen() ) {
    perror("database is not open");
}
query.exec("select accno,branchcode,fname,lname,curbalance,accdate from accounts");
while(query.next()) {
    QString str = query.value(0).toString();
    std::cerr << qPrintable(str) << std::endl;
}
end:
;
}
```

This fails with the following errors...

```
No such file or directory
: Invalid argument
QSqlQuery::exec: database not open
```

Notice that I get "No such file or directory" after adddatabase(), have no clue whatsoever which file is it talking about. Also notice that isOpen() and open() are returning "true" (???). The "database not open" error is from db.exec() call (...I suppose...).

In desperate need of guidance...

Comment: Check the result of exec if the database is opened correctly. Then check using lastError().

Comment: I did do that, the exec( ) call prints _database not open_ error, the third error that i posted in the question (above). And the lastError() returns _Invalid argument_ error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The constructor of QSqlQuery with no parameters uses the default database for your application. Maybe it is not set yet. Use the constructor specifying the database the query is required to use:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "connection_name");
// Open db...
QSqlQuery query(db);
if (!query.exec(...)) {
   // ...
}
// ...
```

Pay attention to how you close the connection afterwards.

EDIT: This is a test I just wrote and is working on my system. You might want to try.

```
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QVariant>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Create database.
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "Connection");
    db.setDatabaseName("/tmp/test.db");
    if (!db.open()) {
        qDebug("Error occurred opening the database.");
        qDebug("%s.", qPrintable(db.lastError().text()));
        return -1;
    }

    // Insert table.
    QSqlQuery query(db);
    query.prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, text TEXT)");
    if (!query.exec()) {
        qDebug("Error occurred creating table.");
        qDebug("%s.", qPrintable(db.lastError().text()));
        return -1;
    }

    // Insert row.
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO test VALUES (null, ?)");
    query.addBindValue("Some text");
    if (!query.exec()) {
        qDebug("Error occurred inserting.");
        qDebug("%s.", qPrintable(db.lastError().text()));
        return -1;
    }

    // Query.
    query.prepare("SELECT * FROM test");
    if (!query.exec()) {
        qDebug("Error occurred querying.");
        qDebug("%s.", qPrintable(db.lastError().text()));
        return -1;
    }
    while (query.next()) {
        qDebug("id = %d, text = %s.", query.value(0).toInt(),
               qPrintable(query.value(1).toString()));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm quite puzzled. You might want to try the code I added to the answer. That creates the database, creates the table, insert a sample row and queries. Please report the output.

Comment: tried it out, its printing _id = 1, text = Some text_ as the result, Is that correct ? I am still a beginner, so I do not understand yet how _addBindValue()_ works, hence I did not understand the printed result.

Comment: Yes,that is correct. If you run it again, you'll see one more line for each execution. The text is constant, the integer will always increment. So everything works fine. Try to use this code to open your database, removing the part that creates the new table and the part that is inserting the new row. Replace test in the query to your table name and test again.

Comment: works flawless man !!!. Just curious...Why is it not good to access database using a pointer ?

Comment: Do you mean QSqlDatabase? I don't think that is a problem, never used it that way as far as I can remember but I think it is ok. Just handle removal of connection correctly. That is a quite delicate point. Refer to removeDatabase in the Qt documentation for an explaination.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly guessing, since your code is wrong on quite a few things, including the error reporting.

The most likely problem is that your file path is simply not right, or the user you're running your application with does not have the appropriate permissions on the file and/or directory. (Note: files and directory are case sensitive in Linux.)

`perror` should only be used after calling a system function that actually failed and that sets `errno` when it does. Qt doesn't do that.

Please try running this, and update your question if you still cannot resolve your issue:

```
void MainWindow::func()
{
    // Note: no pointer!
    QSqlDatabase accounts_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    accounts_db.setDatabaseName("/home/user/xyz.db");
    if (!accounts_db.open())
    {
        qDebug() << "Could not open database file:";
        qDebug() << accounts_db.lastError();
        return;
    }
    // Note: don't construct queries before you have a database!
    QSqlQuery query;
    if (!query.exec("select accno,branchcode,fname,lname,curbalance,accdate from accounts"))   
    {
        qDebug() << "Query failed:";
        qDebug() << query.lastError();
        return;
    }
    while(query.next()) {
      QString str = query.value(0).toString();
      std::cerr << qPrintable(str) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

(I haven't even tried to compile this, so YMMV.)

Have a look at the [SQL examples](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/examples-sql.html) also, and look at how they handle all this there.

Comment: Thanks man... I tried it out. _qDebug() << db.lastError();_ keeps printing _QSqlError(-1, "", "")_ . In fact all the lastError() calls are printing that same thing, except query.exec(). That one is printing _QSqlError(1, "Unable to execute statement", "no such column: accdate")_ . But of course, those columns do exist, I've chkd using cmdline sqlite3 program.  The SQL examples aren't using database files, they are using ":memry:" instead of database filepath.

Answer (score -1):

Alright, I created a brand new database file using *sqlite3* command, now the same program in my question is working !!!.

I had also tried this before, but that time it did not work (...I hate it when that happens). I guess the previous file may be corrupted. But the previous database file could be accessed from cmdline sqlite3 program, so I was assuming that file was ok,...but apparently not.

Anyway, thanks a lot guys for giving me time, and very sorry if I wasted it :( .

I am marking this as an answer just for the sake of clarity that this question is answered. But its not exactly an *answer* (...because I still don't understand what was happening !? )

Thanks again...

EDIT :

Here is the code

```
QSqlError *a = new QSqlError();

accounts_db = new QSqlDatabase();
*accounts_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");

accounts_db->setDatabaseName("/home/user/test.db");

if ( !accounts_db->open() ) {
    qDebug() << accounts_db->lastError();
    qDebug() << "Could not open database file:";
}
QSqlQuery query;

if ( !(accounts_db->isOpen()) ) {
    qDebug() << accounts_db->lastError();
    qDebug() << ": Could not open database file:";
    goto end;   // quit if not successful
}

query.exec("select * from accounts");

while(query.next()) {
    // loop for i columns
    QString str = query.value(i).toString();
    std::cerr << qPrintable(str) << std::endl ;
    // loop
}
end:
;
```

Comment: Please post your revised code without all the stuff (esp. the `perror` stuff) in your answer if you plan on accepting it, otherwise other people might come to think that the code in your question is valid, which is **not** the case.

Comment: Actually it **IS** the case, my previous code **IS** working. All I did was try the same code on a different database file :) . But I am posting the code just in case....to avoid confusion.

Comment: Sorry, your code is not good. You're allocating a QSqlDatabase, then throwing it away right afterwards (leak). Same thing with a QSqlError. You're using QSqlDatabase via a pointer which is not how you're supposed to use it. You're not checking the return value of query.execute() which is **bad practice**. You've got a useless goto which is really bad practice, especially in C++. You're not breaking out of your program flow if the database failed to open, which is **bad practice**. Sorry, -1 from me.

Comment: Well, I only posted the parts of the code which were useful in the answer. I agree, the _GOTO_'s are dangerous, I _SHOULD_ avoid them. But I was using it to break out of the above function, the _end:_ label at the bottom of the code is where I was jumping, de-allocating the resources and then exiting. As I said, I'm quite new to C++ and OOP. Btw, why is it wrong to access database using a pointer ?

Comment: It's not wrong, it's not usual. It's not how it is done in the samples. It leads to leaks (as in your code). gotos are harder to get right in C++ than in C, there is no point in doing a goto to the end of the function if you don't do cleanups there.